# For all I know, he left last night

Tags: modal-verbs, idiomatic-language

Are the following sentences both correct? If so, is there any difference?

> For all I know, he left last night.

> For all I know, he might have left last night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference in meaning.

*might have + past participle* implies less probability that an action took place - we are *unsure* that happened, so it might have happened.

The past simple example indicates a terminated period without expressing a hypothetical situation.

Comment: The problem is that "For all I know" already indicates something is uncertain. Therefore, the first example, the one with non-modal past tense, already indicates that the speaker is uncertain about the truth of the statement.

Comment: Doesn't matter. The modal adds improbability on top of all that.